# Javascript - initializing a class with a setter where set method is of the same name as the field throws: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

I have a component where I am initializing a class that has a setter.
This is the component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.errorLoggGateway = new ErrorLoggGateway();
}
```

And this is the **ErrorLoggGateway** class:

```
import {fetchConvenienceWrapper} from "./fetchTools";

export class ErrorLoggGateway {
  constructor() {
    this.id = null;
  }

  set id(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  loggError(error) {
    return fetchConvenienceWrapper('/backend/api/logg', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({error, id: this.id})
    });
  }
}
```

But, when I have it like that, I get an error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
ErrorLoggGateway.set id [as id]
C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/Projects/project/frontend/src/logic/ErrorLoggGateway.js:9
   6 | }
   7 | 
   8 | set id(id) {
>  9 |   this.id = id;
     | ^  10 | }
  11 | RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
ErrorLoggGateway.set id [as id]
C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/Projects/project/frontend/src/logic/ErrorLoggGateway.js:9
   6 | }
   7 | 
   8 | set id(id) {
>  9 |   this.id = id;
     | ^  10 | }
  11 | 
  12 | loggError(error) {
  12 | loggError(error) {
```

If I change the name of the set method then it works, why it is failing when it is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `set id(id)` calling itself via `this.id=`. See with `console.log()`:

```js
class Something{
  set id(id){
    console.log(id);
    this.id=id;
  }
};

new Something().id=10;
```

Solution: name the "private" variable somehow else, like `this._id`.

---

Oh, you asked for explanation. `this.id=` simply calls `set id()` the same way as `new Something().id=` does. A setter is a setter, no matter if the property is accessed from "outside" or "inside" the class.